# React Native: Exception in native call java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:

Tags: android, react-native

I changed the following line to load the bundle file from app`s specific directory instead of the default `/assets` folder:

```
 mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
                .setApplication(getApplication())
                .setCurrentActivity(this)
                .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
                .setJSBundleFile(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "index.android.bundle") // <--- changed from: .setJSMainModulePath("index")
                .addPackages(packages)
                .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
                .build();
```

Full error:

```
E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call
    java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: 
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:601)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:498)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:447)
        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerBase.resetCurrentContext(DevSupportManagerBase.java:707)
        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerBase.onNewReactContextCreated(DevSupportManagerBase.java:617)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1126)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1500(ReactInstanceManager.java:136)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5$2.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1086)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

What went wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to your code:

```
.setJSMainModulePath("index")
```

from the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java):

> Path to your app's main module on Metro. This is used when reloading
> JS during development. All paths are relative to the root folder the
> packager is serving files from. Examples: {@code "index.android"} or
> {@code "subdirectory/index.android"}